# Error: could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/stretch

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi, raspbian, raspberry-pi3

I am currently working on a project that needs to use object detection. For this I wanted to use OpenCV with Python, since it is the best option because image processing will be fast and easier to read in terms of code. For this project I am using a Raspberry Pi 3 model B, and a raspbi camera.
To get straight to the point.
I have updated Raspbian to Streatch. I went through all the procedures to install OpenCV, but when i needed to add a repository
python-opencv, it tells me that it ¨ could not find a distribution template for Raspbian/stretch¨. What should I do?
Should I reinstall Jessie/Wheezy and start all over again?